# How can I programmatically save a Sublime Text 3 workspace (without a dialog box)?

Tags: sublimetext3

I really want a way to switch programming contexts quickly without hunting for windows that I've left strewn about. What would be nice is a command line tool to let me switch between different patches that I might be working on, and automatically open the sublime text workspace that I had open the last time I was working on that patch. The issue is that in order for the tool to know about the workspaces associated with said patches, it either needs to be told about them explicitly, or it needs to be able to tell sublime to save the current workspace with a specific file path.

Sublime does have a save_workspace_as command, but it opens a saveAs dialog, which is not what I want, and I can't seem to find any documentation that suggests that save_workspace_as can take an argument.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a text editor and not about programming

Comment: @JoshPennington questions regarding tools used primarily for programming are on-topic on SO - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) are all the questions just tagged `[visual-studio]`, for example.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the clarification.